# What is getContentResolver().call() and how to use it

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I have read the documentation on the Android [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html)

I have also searched for a suitable example to no avail.

According to the documentation, there is a method `call` that can be used as a way to get access to custom provider methods when the standard content provider methods are insufficient:

```
final Bundle     call(Uri uri, String method, String arg, Bundle extras)
Call a provider-defined method.
```

so in my code I execute:

```
getContentResolver().call(uri, method, arg, extras);
```

**but it always returns** `null` **bundle**.  In fact, the method in the **provider** never gets called.

Further research points to a (perceived) discrepancy of the contract where the **RESOLVER** has a **uri argument** with no equivalent **PROVIDER** parameter:

```
Bundle   call(String method, String arg, Bundle extras)
Call a provider-defined method.
```

I am obviously not understanding something.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Does your `ContentProvider` have a method that matches the name in the `method` String?

Comment: Yes.  I have a method in the provider that is declared 'public' that is passed into the contentresolver argument 'method.'

Comment: It will probably help us be able to answer your question if you provide some (minimal) example code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Further research points to a discrepancy of the contract where the RESOLVER has a uri argument with no equivalent PROVIDER parameter

That's the way they wrote it. The `Uri` is simply to identify the `ContentProvider` -- the `ContentProvider` knows who it is and therefore does not need the `Uri`.

> the provider method does not allow @Override annotation

Yes, it does, as you can see in [this sample `ContentProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Database/ConstantsSecure/src/com/commonsware/android/sqlcipher/Provider.java):

```
  @Override
  public Bundle call(String method, String arg, Bundle extras) {
    if (SET_KEY_METHOD.equals(method) && arg != null) {
      key=arg;
    }

    return(null);
  }
```

However, your build target (e.g., in Eclipse, Project > Properties > Android) must be set to API Level 11 or higher.

The corresponding `call()` from [the client](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Database/ConstantsSecure/src/com/commonsware/android/sqlcipher/ConstantsBrowser.java) looks like:

```
getContentResolver().call(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI,
                          Provider.SET_KEY_METHOD, "sekrit", null);
```

> Yes. I have a method in the provider that is declared 'public' that is passed into the contentresolver argument 'method.'

That's not how it works. `call()` on `ContentResolver` calls `call()` on your `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Mea cupla.  After cleaning the project the request to remove the @override annotation magically disappeared.

Comment: Is it a good practice to rely on this method? Does ContentProvider with only call() method defined show right usage?

Comment: @sandrstar: "Is it a good practice to rely on this method?" -- if you are the author of the `ContentProvider` and its consumer, sure. "Does ContentProvider with only call() method defined show right usage?" -- IMHO, no. `call()` is, at best, an add-on to base `ContentProvider` functionality. For just procedural work, a `ContentProvider` is useless.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation ! I thought these methods were called through reflection.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, my guess is that the `ContentProvider` version of `call()` does not need a `Uri` argument because, unlike a `ContentResolver`, it doesn't need to find a `ContentProvider`; it calls the method on itself.

Comment: Obviously using contentresolvers/providers does not enforce contracts in the typical object oriented model.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Which is another issue than the one discussed here.